# Informix JDBC login fails, local login succeeds

Tags: jdbc, informix, dbvisualizer

I'm troubleshooting a "sudden" issue on our somewhat old Informix server (11.50.UC9GE). After years of running without issue (and connecting w/o issue), suddenly today we can't connect to the server *remotely*.

When I use dbaccess locally on the server and choose a connection method that prompts for username / password, the credentials work fine and I'm able to establish a connection. (note I can also intentionally enter invalid credentials and it will fail). This leads me to believe that the basic credentials I have are fine / unchanged.

However, when we try to connect to the server remotely (via a JDBC driver in DB Visualizer), we get this error:

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
Incorrect password or user com.informix.asf.IfxASFRemoteException: informix@ip-10-15-45-226.ec2.internal[MacBook-Pro.local] is not known on the database server.

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLException
   Error Code: -951
   SQL State: IX000
```

Up until today, this has always worked for us - any thoughts on what to check?

Comment: I think you need to first understand what changed between the last time you were able to connect remotely and today. The error message hints that the client might be sending an incorrect user ID.

Comment: Yeah, this has been the focus, however we're turning up nothing. All of our remote clients stopped working at the same time, so it must be something on the server side....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately an Informix restart solved the issue.